# Table doesn't work with Slot

Tags: slot, table

Using Mathematica, I was trying to get {#1,#2,#3,#4,#5}, using Table[#n, {n, 1, 5}] Instead I only got {#n, #n, #n, #n, #n} How can I get {#1,#2,#3,#4,#5},

Comment: `Table[Slot[i], {i, 5}]`

Comment: Or instead of `Table`, use `Slot /@ Range[5]`

Comment: You have been a member for several years now. I note that you don't format your posts correctly and haven't been accepting any answers for a while now. Your participation is important.

Answer (score 4):

Shortest would be to use [`Array`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html):

```
Array[Slot, 5]

(*    {#1, #2, #3, #4, #5}    *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solns. In the meantime I also came up with: Table[ToExpression["#" <> ToString[n]], {n, 5}] , but the other solutions are more elegant.